# Fitting RTD Data using axial dispersion model to estimate Peclet number

Tags: python, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am a beginner in code and python as well. In the case of my research works, I need to fit experimental data from Residence Time Distribution to the Axial dispersion model (using closed-closed boundary condition) in order to estimate the Peclet number.

I have already done it with Excel but I'd like to "go deeper" with python. Any proposition will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.